# usage: scarcely any

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, semantics

In the following sentences, the use of "any" seems correct in the first sentence but incorrect in the second. Do you know why?

> 1. Scarcely **any** space occupied by John is clean.
> 2. The porky fellow came into the cubicle, leaving me scarcely **any** room in which I was standing.

Answer (score 3):

'Scarcely any room' means 'not much room' or 'almost no room'. The usage is correct in both sentences, but the second one has an error elsewhere:

> The porky fellow came into the cubicle, leaving me scarcely any room
> `in which I was standing`.

This last phrase is not needed; it doesn't really mean anything. You could write `in which to stand`, but it is understood from the context that 'not much room' means 'not much room in which to move, feel comfortable, etc'. Also, 'porky fellow' is both impolite and informal. This may be what you intended, if not, 'large man', 'bulky person', etc may be better.

[Scarcely (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scarcely)